# Installing iOS app with distribution certificate looks disabled and does not open

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, phonegap-build

I have created an iOS app with Phonegap. First I used a development certificate and a profile to install it in my iPad. It works perfectly.

After that I created a distribution certificate and a profile to upload it to the App Store. I created the .ipa on Build Phonegap from the same source code with no problems. However, when I try to install it on the same iPad using iTunes it doesn't work.

After the installing process the icon is a default one instead of mine, and it looks disabled. When I click on it the name changes to "Waiting..." and it is stuck like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download app from app store. 
If you sign app with distribution certificate and a profile it will not run on device. Because you cant add deviceID's in distribution profiles.